# Script Javascript retornando SyntaxError: missing ; before statement apenas no firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Tenho uma função em javascript para ler arquivos que estão dentro do servidor. Em todos os navegadores ela funiona perfeitamente, com exceção do firefox que retorna o erro:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Código da função:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function lerArquivo(arquivo) {
  var response;
  jQuery.get(arquivo, function(data) {
      response = data;
  }, 'text');
  await sleep(500);
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Qual seria a linha do erro?

Comment: No firefox acusa a primeira linha após o termino da função sleep, ou seja, a linha em que eu declaro a função lerArquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe nenhum erro no código postado, porém um navegador desatualizado irá acusar erros porque as palavras chaves async e await só foram introduzidos no ES2017, e portanto o browser não será capaz de rodar esse código.

Vou aproveitar para citar: você está fazendo mal uso do AJAX em seu código. Ao invés de retornar a resposta após obtê-la do servidor, você está esperando meio segundo e então tentando retornar o que você obteve. Mas e se a resposta demorar mais de meio segundo para retornar?
Você poderia muito bem utilizar

```
function lerArquivo(arquivo) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jQuery.get(arquivo, 'text')
          .done(resolve)
          .fail(reject);
  });
}
```